# clang-AST traversal - How to get member variables of a class

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to traverse the AST of a simple class having one member variable and one method. I have figured out that the class is represented as CXXRecordDecl.

What is the api within CXXREcordDecl to get the list of member variables which are represented as FieldDecl ?

Comment: It would be easier to override VisitFieldDecl instead.

Answer (score 5):

The fields can be retrieved with `RecordDecl::fields` (there exist also methods the get the begin and end iterators of that range), e.g. for a `CXXRecordDecl`

```
CXXRecordDecl* cl = ...;
for (const auto& field : cl->fields) {
    const auto& name = field->getName();
    const auto field_cl = field->getType()->getAsCXXRecordDecl(); 
}
```

Similarly you would access the methods with `methods()`.